# Can I connect to mongoose from within a test?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, chai

I'm trying to run a chai test that connects to mongodb using mongoose, but it is failing with 'expected undefined to be an object'. I'm using the same method that I use in the functioning app. Am I connecting to the database correctly?

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var eeg = require('../eegFunctions');
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function callback(){console.log('db ready');});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/eegControl');

test("lastShot() should return an object", function(){

    var data;
    eeg.lastShot(function(eegData){
        data = eegData;
    });
    return expect(data).to.eventually.be.an('object');        

});
```

Comment: What line do you get that error on? EDIT: Nevermind... answer coming...

Comment: What other testing framework are you using? I mean, what `test` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're [test is asynchronous](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) because the connection to Mongo is asynchronous, so you need to make the assertion happen when the connection is complete:

```
test("lastShot() should return an object", function(done){  // Note the "done" argument

    var data;
    eeg.lastShot(function(eegData){
        data = eegData;

        // do your assertions in here, when the async action executes the callback...
        expect(data).to.eventually.be.an('object');

        done(); // tell Mocha we're done with async actions
    });

    // (no need to return anything)
});
```